B-spline with smoothing penalty generalized to 2D
Let $s(t)=(x_{s},y_{s})=(g_{1}(x(t)),g_{2}(y(t))),$ be the B-spline
curve given by
$$
g_{1}(x(t))=\mathbf{B}_{x}\beta_{x},\qquad g_{2}(y(t))=\mathbf{B}_{y}(t)\beta_{y},
$$
where $\mathbf{B}_{x}(t),$ $\mathbf{B}_{y}(t)$ are the B-spline
basis and $\beta{}_{x},\beta{}_{y}$are the B-spline $s(t)$ coefficients.
The spline tries to generalize 1D strategies (residuals + smoothing) to 2D.
Spline $s(t)$ minimizes the energy $E(s(t))=E_{1}(s(t))+E_{2}(s(t))$,
$E_{1}(s(t))$ are the residuals
$$
E_{1}(s(t))=(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{B}_{x}\beta_{x})^{T}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{B}_{x}\beta_{x})+(\mathbf{\mathbf{y}}-\mathbf{B}_{y}\beta_{y})^{T}(\mathbf{\mathbf{y}}-\mathbf{B}_{y}\beta_{y})
$$
and $E_{2}(s(t))$ is the proposed smoothing penalty
$$
E_{2}(s(t))=\beta_{x}^{T}\mathbf{B}_{x}^{T}\mathbf{\mathbf{D}}^{T}\mathbf{\mathbf{D}}\mathbf{B}_{x}\beta_{x}+\beta_{y}^{T}\mathbf{B}_{y}^{T}\mathbf{\mathbf{D}}_{}^{T}\mathbf{\mathbf{D}}_{}\mathbf{B}_{y}\beta_{y},
$$
$\mathbf{D}$ is the finite differce matrix (second derivative). Minimizing $E(s(t))$ from the conditions $\partial E(s(t))/\partial\beta_{x}=0$,
$\partial E(s(t))/\partial\beta_{y}=0$
$$
-2\mathbf{B}_{x}^{T}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{B}_{x}\beta_{x})+2\mathbf{B}_{x}^{T}\mathbf{\mathbf{D}}^{T}\mathbf{\mathbf{D}}\mathbf{B}_{x}\beta_{x}=0,\quad-2\mathbf{B}_{y}^{T}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{B}_{y}\beta_{y})+2\mathbf{B}_{x}^{T}\mathbf{\mathbf{D}}^{T}\mathbf{\mathbf{D}}\mathbf{B}_{x}\beta_{x}=0,
$$
leads to
$$
\beta_{x}=(\mathbf{B}_{x}^{T}\mathbf{B}_{x}+\mathbf{B}_{x}^{T}\mathbf{\mathbf{D}}^{T}\mathbf{\mathbf{D}}\mathbf{B}_{x})^{-1}\mathbf{B}_{x}^{T}\mathbf{x},\quad\beta_{y}=(\mathbf{B}_{y}^{T}\mathbf{B}_{y}+\mathbf{B}_{y}^{T}\mathbf{\mathbf{D}}^{T}\mathbf{\mathbf{D}}\mathbf{B}_{y})^{-1}\mathbf{B}_{y}^{T}\mathbf{y}.
$$
Surprisingly, for the B-spline bases
$$
\mathbf{B}_{x}(t)=[1,x,x^{2}],\mathbf{B}_{y}(t)=[1,y,y^{2}]
$$
and points $[0,0],[10,0],[10,10],[0,10]$ we get
$$
\mathbf{B}_{x}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 10 & 100\\
1 & 10 & 100\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right],\mathbf{B}_{y}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 10 & 100\\
1 & 10 & 100
\end{array}\right],\beta_{x}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
10/3\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right]=\beta_{y},
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{x}_{s}=\mathbf{B}_{x}\beta_{x}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
10/3\\
10/3\\
10/3\\
10/3
\end{array}\right]=\mathbf{B}_{y}\beta_{y}=\mathbf{y}_{s}.
$$
Hence, the smoothing spline "projects" the square into a point,
which is incorrect. Where is the problem? For example, a wrong design
of the smoothing penalty?
Thanks for your help.
Updated question:
Here is the Matlab code:
%Data
X = [0; 10; 10; 0];
Y = [0; 0; 10; 10];
m = length(X);

%Base functions
Bx = [ones(m, 1), X, X .* X];
By = [ones(m, 1), Y, Y .* Y];

%Spline
E = eye(m, m);
D = diff(E, 2);
Dx = D * Bx;
Dy = D * By;
bx = inv( Bx' * Bx + Dx'* Dx) * Bx'*X;
by = inv( By' * By + Dy'* Dy) * By'*Y;

%Solution
XS = Bx * bx;
YS = By * by;

hold on;
plot (X', Y', 'b');
plot (Xs, Ys, 'r');


It seems that neither $E_1$ nor $E_2$ has any built-in "bivariate" nature, i.e., without any "inter-correlations" linking the two dimensions together. It looks like dealing with the two dimensions separately.

@Zack Fisher: I tried to generalize 1D approaches (residuals + smoothing penalty )to 2D. However, it may not work, as appeared.
